# R: Find closest value in large array and return dimensions

Tags: arrays, r

I'd like to find the nearest value to `x` in a large two dimensional array (`my.array`) and return the the i and j indexes where i is `[1:175]` and j is `[1:120]`.

```
x <- 1.863
my.array <- array(rnorm(21000), dim=c(175,120))
```

On searching on stack overflow and other sites I've found I can find the nearest value like so:

```
nearest <- which.min(abs(my.array - x))
```

However this returns a single locater value whereas I would like to return the i and j index values.

```
> nearest
[1] 13229
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`help(which.min)`

says, near the bottom:

> ...
>   Use arrayInd(), if you need array/matrix indices instead of 1D vector ones.

Aha! Well then:

```
# make the example reproducible
set.seed(123)

x <- 1.863
my.array <- array(rnorm(21000), dim=c(175,120))
nearest <- which.min(abs(my.array - x)) 
idx <- arrayInd(nearest, .dim=dim(my.array))
idx
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2]
> [1,]   46   62
> ```

Dropping the unused dimensions is not necessary, but it keeps me from getting confused, so I do it. The example works the same way if you skip the `drop()` statement.

```
# drop unused dimensions:
idx <- drop(idx)
idx
```

> ```
> [1] 46 62
> ```

```
# check:
my.array[idx[1], idx[2]]
```

> ```
> [1] 1.863453
> ```